# What is a CM Teleport?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In [this twitter conversation](https://mobile.twitter.com/EEAbdullah/status/449576422102016000?p=v), reference is made to a **"CM Teleport"**. What does that mean? What does CM stand for in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are referring to challenge modes.  The harder, timed versions of dungeons.  When you complete any challenge mode dungeon you unlock the ability to teleport to that dungeon at any time (on an 8 hour cooldown for each teleport).

Source:
http://wow.joystiq.com/2012/07/27/challenge-modes-provide-new-teleportation-options/

Comment: they have 8 hour cooldowns

Comment: You only unlock the teleport if you get a gold ranking.